# update 2 fields using linq foreach

Tags: c#, linq

Can I update 2 fields using linq foreach loop at once?
Sample snippet :
 I have a userdata with Name, Email, CreateTime, LastUpdateTime fields.
 I have to reset CreateTime and LastUpdateTime for all users.

To update i am using 2 calls as below

```
users.ForEach(x => x.CreateTime= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1));
users.ForEach(x => x.LastUpdateTime = DateTime.Now);
```

instead can I do it in a single using linq foreach loop?

Comment: While I get the not linq part, I don't understand the downvote. The OP is clearly trying to learn and downvoting a brand new user isn't exactly being helpful. As far as I can tell, the question has all the normal elements in it, isn't it?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Well to start with, assuming this is `List<T>.ForEach`, this *isn't* using LINQ. But yes, you can create a lambda expression using a statement body:

```
users.ForEach(x => {
    x.CreateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
    x.LastUpdateTime = DateTime.Now;
});
```

However, you may *also* want to use one consistent time for all the updates:

```
DateTime updateTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime createTime = updateTime.AddMonths(-1);

users.ForEach(x => {
    x.CreateTime = createTime;
    x.LastUpdateTime = updateTime;
});
```

It's not really clear *why* you want to achieve it this way though. I would suggest using a `foreach` loop instead:

```
DateTime updateTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime createTime = updateTime.AddMonths(-1);

foreach (var user in users)
{
    user.CreateTime = createTime;
    user.LastUpdateTime = updateTime;
}
```

Comment: the link doesn't work. can you repost the correct link as i am not able to find it ?

Comment: @Thameem: Unfortunately I don't think it exists any more. I'll remove it from the answer.

Answer (score 9):

It's actually not linq, but you can try

```
users.ForEach(x => { x.CreateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
                     x.LastUpdateTime = DateTime.Now; });
```